# Bellman's equation's loss in TFjs

Tags: javascript, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning, tensorflow.js

I am trying to implement a simple Pong Q-Network in JS using p5 and tfjs.
To train the network, I first created a custom loss function where I passed a label tensor only containing the labels for the actions a_t

[image: label_image]

TFjs didn't really seemed to like the fact that the shape was different from the predictions from the model, so I crafted another custom loss function where the label input is a tensor of shape `[batchSize, 3]` (3 actions up, down and none) where each element is in the form `[0,0,y_j]` or `[0,y_j,0]` or `[y_j,0,0]` (y_j at the place I am supposed to compare to the predictions tensor and 0 elsewhere). Here it is:

```
function bellmanLoss(predictions, labels)
{
    let predictions_buffer = predictions.buffer();
    let labels_buffer = labels.buffer();
    let length = labels.shape[0];
    predictions.dispose();
    labels.dispose();
    let loss = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        for(let j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            if(labels_buffer.get(i,j) != 0)
            {
                loss += Math.pow(labels_buffer.get(i,j) - predictions_buffer.get(i,j), 2);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return tf.tensor(loss);
}
```

But here I am crafting a tensor from scratch and so I get this error using `model.fit: "Error: Cannot find a connection between any variable and the result of the loss function y=f(x)`. Please make sure the operations that use variables are inside the function f passed to minimize()".
Is there a way to have a loss compatible with `model.fit` or do I have to tune the model weights manually (which would be a pain)?

Update : I've made some changes to be more "tensory" and it seem to go in the right direction:

```
function bellmanLoss(preds, labels)
{
    let mask = tf.cast(labels, 'bool');
    let zeros = tf.zerosLike(preds);
    let clean_preds = preds.where(mask, zeros);
    return tf.squaredDifference(clean_preds, labels).mean();
}
```

However, I still need to find another alternative because

> "Error: Cannot compute gradient: gradient function not found for where"

Final update: I've found a way without using tf.where and it works

```
function bellmanLoss(preds, labels)
{
    let mask_b = tf.cast(labels, 'bool');
    let mask = tf.cast(mask_b, 'float32');
    let clean_preds = preds.mul(mask);
    return tf.squaredDifference(clean_preds, labels).mean();
}
```

Comment: You are using `.buffer()` wrong. This just creates an empty buffer. If you want the values of a tensor use `.data()` or `.dataSync()`.